# Kotlin how to properly use Android Intent to save file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am currently trying to save a text file inside a fragment, but I can't get it to work:

Here is the method called when the user clicks the save button

```
    private fun saveText(){
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "*/*"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "text.txt")
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
    }
```

Here is the onActivityResult method:

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, resultData: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            val path = resultData?.data?.path
            Log.wtf("Path", filePath)
            val writer: Writer = BufferedWriter(FileWriter(path))
            writer.write("Example Text")
            writer.close()
        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

I also have the permissions set in the manifest and the file itself is created, but nothing is written. Perhaps I'm writing to the file wrong?

The error thrown is FileNotFoundException, because its trying to use a file from /document when I'm selecting one from /downloads

Suggested solution which unfortunately doesn't work:

```
                resultData?.data?.let {
                requireActivity().contentResolver.openOutputStream(it).use { stream ->
                    stream!!.bufferedWriter().write("Example Text")
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Uri` is not a file.

Replace:

```
        val path = resultData?.data?.path
        Log.wtf("Path", filePath)
        val writer: Writer = BufferedWriter(FileWriter(path))
        writer.write("Example Text")
        writer.close()
```

with:

```
resultData?.data?.let { contentResolver.openOutputStream(it).use { stream ->
    stream.writer().write("Example Text")
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, it comes up with the error  resultData?.data inside the brackets is Uri? and needs Uri. It suggests wrapping with a let call, would you recommend that?

Comment: @john: Oh, yeah, sorry, forgot that part -- I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply again, for some reason it still isn't writing anything to the file. I've added your suggestion to the question to show how it was implemented, should also note I've specified its a fragment if that will make any difference

Comment: @john: Switch from `bufferedWriter()` to `writer()` and see if that helps (see updated answer).